# Index a Pandas DataFrame/Series by Series of indices

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to create a pandas Series which is based on values within another DataFrame. A simplified example would be:

```
df_idx = pd.DataFrame([0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3])
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame([10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0])
```

where I wish to generate a new pandas series of values drawn from df_lookup based on the indices in df_idx, i.e.:

```
df_target = pd.DataFrame([10.0, 30.0, 30.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0])
```

Clearly, it is desirable to do this without looping for speed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df_lookup.loc[df_idx[0]]`

Comment: Hey, thanks Quang Hoang, I think that's just the ticket

Comment: Are you trying to get rows from a DataFrame? Specific elements using their full coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `reindex` is for:

```
df_idx = pd.DataFrame([0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3])
df_lookup = pd.DataFrame([10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0])

df_lookup.reindex(df_idx[0])
```

Output:

```
      0
0      
0  10.0
2  30.0
2  30.0
3  40.0
1  20.0
3  40.0
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, appreciate the response. Both your solution and Quang Hoang's comment on my question achieve the result I was after.

Answer (score -1):

This is precisely the use case for `iloc`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0])
idx_lst = pd.Series([0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3])

res = df.iloc[idx_lst]
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/indexing.html#indexing-integer) for more on indexing by position.

Comment: @ska_james is this a bit more clear than my original answer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response Alexander, this also achieves the result I was after, in addition to Quang's comment and Scott's answer. I'm sure there are several ways to achieve this, and I can't comment as to which is better/more correct. I note though that someone has downvoted your answer; perhaps it would be helpful if they or someone else could comment as to why this solution is not preferred?

Comment: @ska_james Well there are a few differences between the solutions. For example, the `loc` solution suggested by Quang Hoang works on any index, whereas `iloc` is only for integer indexes.

Comment: @ska_james There also seem to be some performance differences, `iloc` is faster than the other alternatives.